# How to retrieve google api next page results using nextpageToken in java

Tags: java, oauth, google-api

I am facing 500 Internal Server Error when trying to fetch next page using the page token. I appended pageToken to the query

query+"&pageToken=[nextPageToken]"

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue. Append %3D%3D to the url to eliminate unsafe characters in the page token like ==. The url format should be query+"&pageToken=[nextPageToken]%3D%3D"